# Monterey automount of ntfs RW partition

Tags: ntfs, automount

before writing I made a lot of trials and I did read a lot of posts and google results: the results are or very old and no more working or claiming the `/etc/fstab` solution is no more working and that one should make "my hand" `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/Disk1TB` without specifying that this must be done every single time...

I summarize (also adding weird things I see):

1. Installed ntfs-3g for Mac, via brew with `brew install ntfs-3g-mac`.
2. if I do:

   ```
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/Disk1TB            
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> touch /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> ls /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova   
   /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> ls -lh /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 bozzo  staff     0B  4 Lug 15:47 /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova
   ```

   I'm able to mount RW.
3. if I do:

   ```
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto /dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/Disk1TB 
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> touch /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova                      
   touch: /Volumes/Disk1TB/prova: Read-only file system
   ```

   I'm not able to write anymore... Why `nobrowse` is interfering with the writeability?
4. if I have an `/etc/fstab` like this:

   ```
   bozzo@host-10-25-128-252:duranti> cat /etc/fstab           
   #
   # Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
   #
   # Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
   #
   #UUID=F842A87E-2203-4DD4-A1E3-7F63B8E8DB91 /Volumes/Disk1TB  ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse 0 0
   /dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/Disk1TB  ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse 0 0
   ```

   the disk is mounted in RO, and with the name of the Volume (i.e. under `/Volumes/Elements` and not `/Volumes/Disk1TB`, so using the standard OS X feature...). Same if I use the UUID.

Any idea on how to mount an ntfs drive, in the path I choose, RW, **automatically**?

Comment: idk the tuxera install, I do it a different way, but it should just auto-mount on hot-plug, once set up properly. idk if this might help - https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand the answer: the auto-mount is NOT working so "once set up properly" is exactly the question: how?

Comment: Can I also ask David why my question has been edited?